# Cannot use j_spring_security_check value in form

Tags: java

Login form have wrong action parameter value for **j_spring_security_check**. Spring 3 have not translated it to valid url for login page.

**part of resulted login page**

```
<form id="command" name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>;" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login"
                    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                    default-target-url="/main"
                    authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="testuser" password="testpassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="banner">Login to Security Demo</h1>
<form:form name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value="testuser" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' value="testpassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix it?

---

Update

spring security 3.2.4.RELESASE libraries are used.

---

UPDATE2:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">
    <display-name>APP</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: I suppose that you get errors in the logs, what are those errors ?

Comment: You'll need to use logs if you want to do serious JEE programming. Where they are depends on the servlet container used and how it is run. When using IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans you see them directly in the IDE. But what it the error in your browser at minimum ?

Comment: No errors. `j_spring_security_check` is being received on the browser side as plain text.

Comment: Ouch, should have been processed by a filter ... What is your web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure without more details on the errors, but  in login.jsp, you have `action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>"` - think it would be better to set an absolute path `action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>"`.